# YQL: select woeid returning null

Tags: api, yql, yahoo-api

I use YQL to get weather data for that woeid is needed, but to get woeid when i call following url it return result null

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%27delhi%27&format=json
```

Result i received

```
{"query":{"count":0,"created":"2018-03-14T10:51:42Z","lang":"en-US","results":null}}
```

Even on https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/ it's  showing null.

Is there any other way to get woeid for yahoo weather.

Best Regards, Ashish

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem!! 
I have a scheduled script that cycles the temperatures of some cities and that has received data until this morning at 07:00 gmt + 1. 
I think it depends on the yahoo service! 
maybe they have modified some parameters

Comment: It started just 1 hour back.

Answer (score 0):

Should be working.  I emailed yql-team@yahoo-inc.com yesterday about this issue being down, did not get a response but the issues is resolved on my end.